# Train an estimator with text features

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, supervised-learning

I have a labeled training data set like so

```
X = [tag, design_version, runtime, error_msg], Y = 'PASS'/'FAIL'
'tag' = string
'design_version' = string
'runtime' = number
'error_msg' = string
```

There are many more features (strings, numbers) that I have access to but haven't listed here for brevity. The data is actually a set of attributes for simulations, and the labels are whether the simulation passed or failed. I want to train an estimator with these inputs; and make it predict 'PASS' or 'FAIL' on a new set of attributes.

I have been reading up on [Working with Text Data with sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html). But not really clear on how to use a combination of text and numeric features to fit an estimator to. What algorithm to use etc.

Any pointers will be really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scikit-learn provides a nice utility class called [FeatureUnion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html#sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion) which allows to combine several feature extraction methods (i.e. concatenate feature vectors produced by them). There is a [tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-hetero-feature-union-py) on how to combine different feature types. Basically, you can do something like this:

```
fe = FeatureUnion([
    ('tag', Pipeline([
        ('selector', ItemSelector(key='tag')),
        ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(3,5), analyzer='char'))),
    ])),
    ('runtime',  # ...transformer for runtime feature
    # ... etc
])
```

(ItemSelector is a custom class defined in the tutorial).

Comment: This is pretty much EXACTLY what I was hoping to find! While it might take me a while to actually try this out and get it working, but I am pretty sure this is what I need. Thanks a whole bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform the string type data into numbers. There are different methods for this like one-hot-encoding, label encoding, tf-idf, etc. This methods depends on how your data works, but first of all you can binarize your Y values so if pass its 1 and if you fail it's 0.

Comment: For some attributes, an encoding scheme is easy to implement. But then it's not a continuous number that can be used in a mathematical computation. I mean, a house area is a continuous value (the more the area, more weight it adds); but an encoded value cannot directly correlate to the label numerically right? I can encode my tags into 0, 1, 2 (say). But that doesn't indicate "as tag number increases, more labels are seen to be FAIL" or something.

Comment: Right for some attributes, nominal attributes you can label it. If you already have continuous values leave them like that. You need to change transform the nominal attributes to ordinal you your model can be trained.

Comment: "change transform the nominal attributes to ordinal" - what does this mean? I was thinking about using k-NN approach. Since k-NN looks at distances between features, I could use a string-distance metric for the string attributes. If that would work, I would not even need to convert string features to numbers and what not.

Comment: The idea is that you need a feature vector. This vector have only numbers. You need to select which attributes are useful for the model, because not all the attributes are useful. To change nominal to ordinal is to change something like "True" and "False" to 1 and 0. You can give a number to each class. For other features you have to evaluate how you can make this transformation.

Comment: Thanks for the input Franco!